# django-social-auth : Login with different social account with email authentication

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I want to authenticate the email if it already exist its redirect to that account. This will achieve when I LOGIN using social account. I'm using django-social-auth for my login page. If I login using google it takes information from google and stored it in my database. Its perfect one. Then I login using facebook in facebook having same email which is in google account. In this situation It will allow to access previous account which is created by using gmail. No need create new acount. If any one answer me it would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I want to authenticate the email if it already exist its redirect to that account. This will achieve when I LOGIN using social account

Comment: You probably want to redirect the user, if the email exists in your database, to the login page and not to the account.

Comment: It is also possible to associate multiple user accounts with a single email address, set value as True to enable, otherwise set as False to disable. This behavior is disabled by default (False) unless specifically set:

SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_BY_MAIL = True